Deploying Spring Boot application with MySQL using Docker Compose throws a Liquibase error
Tech stack: Java 17, Spring Boot 3.3.2, MySQL 8.0.27, JPA, Liquibase, Docker
I'm trying to deploy Spring Boot application with MySQL using Liquibase as schema migration tool. Here images, containers and database also created successfully. But when Spring Boot app attaching to MySQL it's throwing Liquibase exception
Full stack trace
2024-08-14 22:12:11 
2024-08-14 22:12:11   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2024-08-14 22:12:11  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2024-08-14 22:12:11 ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2024-08-14 22:12:11  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2024-08-14 22:12:11   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2024-08-14 22:12:11  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2024-08-14 22:12:11 
2024-08-14 22:12:11  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.2)
2024-08-14 22:12:11 
2024-08-14 22:12:13 2024-08-14T16:42:13.013Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.digital.library.LibraryApplication   : Starting LibraryApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17-ea with PID 1 (/opt/app.jar started by root in /opt)
2024-08-14 22:12:13 2024-08-14T16:42:13.020Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.digital.library.LibraryApplication   : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2024-08-14 22:12:18 2024-08-14T16:42:18.705Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-08-14 22:12:18 2024-08-14T16:42:18.778Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 61 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-08-14 22:12:19 2024-08-14T16:42:19.542Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8086 (http)
2024-08-14 22:12:19 2024-08-14T16:42:19.557Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-08-14 22:12:19 2024-08-14T16:42:19.557Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.26]
2024-08-14 22:12:19 2024-08-14T16:42:19.670Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-08-14 22:12:19 2024-08-14T16:42:19.672Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6494 ms
2024-08-14 22:12:19 2024-08-14T16:42:19.897Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-08-14 22:12:26 2024-08-14T16:42:26.822Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Failed to initialize dependency 'liquibase' of LoadTimeWeaverAware bean 'entityManagerFactory': Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
2024-08-14 22:12:26 2024-08-14T16:42:26.833Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-08-14 22:12:26 2024-08-14T16:42:26.848Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 
2024-08-14 22:12:26 
2024-08-14 22:12:26 Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-08-14 22:12:26 2024-08-14T16:42:26.876Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
2024-08-14 22:12:26 
2024-08-14 22:12:26 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Failed to initialize dependency 'liquibase' of LoadTimeWeaverAware bean 'entityManagerFactory': Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.collabera.digital.library.LibraryApplication.main(LibraryApplication.java:10) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2024-08-14 22:12:26 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1806) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     ... 17 common frames omitted
2024-08-14 22:12:26 Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:259) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar!/:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     ... 24 common frames omitted
2024-08-14 22:12:26 Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(SpringLiquibase.java:251) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar!/:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:190) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar!/:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:199) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar!/:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:189) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar!/:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:168) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar!/:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:256) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar!/:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:242) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar!/:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     ... 26 common frames omitted
2024-08-14 22:12:26 Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:111) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:98) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:90) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:74) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:885) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:810) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:438) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:189) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:137) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:360) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:461) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:550) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:98) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:111) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(SpringLiquibase.java:246) ~[liquibase-core-4.27.0.jar!/:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     ... 32 common frames omitted
2024-08-14 22:12:26 Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2024-08-14 22:12:26 
2024-08-14 22:12:26 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:104) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:149) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:165) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:88) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:829) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     ... 44 common frames omitted
2024-08-14 22:12:26 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:669) ~[na:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:331) ~[na:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:630) ~[na:na]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:62) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar!/:8.3.0]
2024-08-14 22:12:26     ... 46 common frames omitted
2024-08-14 22:12:26 

This is my application.yml
server:
  port: 8086
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    database: mysql
    database-platform: 'org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect'
    hibernate:
  datasource:
    url: 'jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/collabera?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true'
    username: root
    password: root
    driver-class-name: 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml

docker-compose file
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    image: musni007/collaberadigitallibrary:0.0.1
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/collabera?autoReconnect=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false    
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: admin
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
   
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: collabera
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      

Liqubase master file
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
             http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
      
        <include file="db/changelog/v1.0.0.xml"/>
    
    </databaseChangeLog>

and my create tables changes xml file-v1.0.0.xml
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">

    <changeSet author="Musni" id="01">
        <sqlFile path="db/sql/dump.sql" />
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>

What can I try next to investigate this?

i pulled your repo i cannot pull your image from docker hub @Musni can you allow it so that i can check

Here i provided git link only,image is not avaible in docker hub

✘ mysqldb Error context canceled                                                                        2.6s
✘ app Error     pull access denied for musni007/collaberadigitallibrary, repository does ...            2.6s
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for musni007/collaberadigitallibrary, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
i am already logged in docker through terminal

1.mvn clean package -DskipTests
2.docker build -t collaberadigitallibrary:0.0.1 .
3.docker-compose up    .  if you have installed docker Just 3 steps

yes i think the answer by andy will solve your issue it was just volume bind  in diffrent port and setting container port in datasource instead of host port

Where do you run liquibase? Is it deployed on one of the containers or is it run from the computer where you host the containers?

In general I recommend that a code repository is not supplied in a question. It is not strictly disallowed, but if a question cannot be understood without the link, then the question is off-topic. Moreover, we want to help future readers, and if they look at the repository in a year or two, the code will have moved on, or the repo will be deleted. So, make the question self-contained if you can.

Your port configuration for MySQL looks like it's incorrect.
In a compose file, when you're exposing ports it's declared as HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT. You have 3307:3306 so your MySQL container will make port 3306 in the container available at 3307 in the host. 3306 is the correct container port to use as that's MySQL's default port. 3307 is fine for the host port as long as clients use that port. However, you're using 3306 in your application.yml so MySQL is inaccessible. Changing to 3307 should fix the problem:
spring:
  datasource:
    url: 'jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3307/collabera?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true'


In the application-dev.yml i have change my port as 3307 since i'm using dev envirenment .It not worked out for me,then i removed the  "SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/collabera?autoReconnect=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false" this line from compose file since it's override the my application-dev.yml property .bad luck it's also not working for me

It looks like the issue might be related to the timing of when the app service tries to connect to the mysqldb service. Even though you've specified depends_on, this only ensures that Docker starts the mysqldb service before the app service. It doesn't guarantee that MySQL is ready to accept connections by the time the app service starts.
I think you can enhance the depends_on directive by adding a health check to ensure that the MySQL service is fully operational before the app service starts. Here's how you can modify your Docker Compose file:
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    image: musni007/collaberadigitallibrary:0.0.1
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    depends_on:
      mysqldb:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/collabera?autoReconnect=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false    
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: admin
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
   
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: collabera
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "mysqladmin ping -h localhost -u admin -p root"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

This should prevent your application from trying to connect to the database before it's ready.


Container library-mysqldb-1  Stopping                                                                                                                                                                      0.2s
dependency failed to start: container library-mysqldb-1 is unhealthy     ---> solution not working for me

